# UICollectionView reload data doesn't update cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'd like to preface this by saying I'm used to how UITableViews work and am not super familiar with UICollectionView.

What I'm essentially doing is

1. Add views (including collection view) on screen

```swift
featuredCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: featuredLabel.frame.origin.y + featuredLabel.frame.size.height, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 216), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        featuredCollectionView.delegate = self
        featuredCollectionView.dataSource = self
        featuredCollectionView.register(ItemCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:
        "cell")
        featuredCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.fysGray
        featuredCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        // add view to screen
```

2. Load data from network and add to datasource array

```swift
func fetchPosts()
{
  // note some libs have been changed for x purposes 
  NetworkClass.loadPosts()
  { (data, error) in 
    // parse into valid object 
    // add to datasource array
    self.featuredItems.append(item)

    // reload data 
    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
        self.featuredCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

  }
```

3. `collectionView.reloadData()` on main queue as shown above

After calling reload data nothing appears on screen as if it is blank. I've tried reloading from the main queue and inserting/performing batch updates etc. I'm just really confused on how to get this working. Do I have to know the number of items before I load from the network? How can I get this working?

Here if the code for cellForItemAt

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    var item: Item
    if collectionView == featuredCollectionView
    {
        item = featuredItems[indexPath.row]
    }
    else
    {
        item = recentlyViewedItems[indexPath.row]
    }


    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCollectionViewCell
    cell.item = item
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Check you collectionView frame. I think it now zero. Or surely you set datasource for collectionView.

Comment: Can you add some code too?

Comment: I set a datasource and the frame is not zero. I will post some code

Comment: Do you get data in your Log?

Comment: Yes, data is completely fine. I also print in ` func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int` the number of items and they are not 0

Comment: Can you post the code of cellForItemAtIndexPath?

Comment: Does your CV background show `UIColor.fysGray` and then it shows... white?, blank?,  after reloading?

Comment: You created featuredCollectionView but not add it as subView?

Comment: It shows fysGray the whole time, just no cells present. Debugging the view hierarchy confirms that there is just a blank CV

Comment: It is added as a subview, the line is just missing from the snipit I pasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being a problem with the if condition in the cell method. It didn't like it for some reason, so I used two separate view controllers with a container view and it worked like a charm with `reloadData()`